# Pythng plot axis from table data

Tags: python, plot

I'm learning python and stuck trying to plot data from my table.
Here is piece of my code:

```
    df1 = populationReport.loc[['Time','VIC','NSW','QLD']]

    df1 = df1.set_index('Time')

    print(df1)

    plt.plot(df1)
    plt.legend(df1.columns)
    plt.ylabel ('Population')
    plt.xlabel ('Timeline')


    plt.show()
```

I need the X axis to display information from 'Time' column.
But so far it just displays line numbers in my table.

Attached image displays desired plot but x axis should display not the number of entries but data from 'Time'column
[my draft plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIdeV.png)

Here is how the table looks like:

```
           VIC        NSW        QLD
Time                                    
1/12/05  5023203.0  6718023.0  3964175.0
1/3/06   5048207.0  6735528.0  3987653.0
1/6/06   5061266.0  6742690.0  4007992.0
1/9/06   5083593.0  6766133.0  4031580.0
1/12/06  5103965.0  6786160.0  4055845.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), if necessary define `format` or `dayfirst` parameter:

```
df1 = populationReport[['Time','VIC','NSW','QLD']]
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'], format='%d/%m/%y')
#alternative
#df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'], dayfirst=True)
df1 = df1.set_index('Time')
print (df1)
                  VIC        NSW        QLD
Time                                       
2005-12-01  5023203.0  6718023.0  3964175.0
2006-03-01  5048207.0  6735528.0  3987653.0
2006-06-01  5061266.0  6742690.0  4007992.0
2006-09-01  5083593.0  6766133.0  4031580.0
2006-12-01  5103965.0  6786160.0  4055845.0
```

and then is possible use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax = df1.plot()
ticklabels = df1.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.show()
```